# Merge Replicate, reinitialise with a different part of the data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

I have a set of database with merge replicate configured between them.

The publisher is an aggregate of three sets of data.
Call them set `0`, `1`, and `2`

There are subscribers that grab *one* set of the data depending on their geographical region (in SQL terms the `HOST_NAME()`).

One of the servers was setup with the wrong set.  (`0` instead of `1`).
I have corrected the function responsible so that servers should now get the correct set.
What do I need to do to force that server to dump its current data and grab the correct set all over again?

Marking the SQL server for a reinitialise from subscription did not do the trick :(

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps in [Create a Snapshot for a Merge Publication with Parameterized Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151260.aspx) to generate a new snapshot.  You must first generate a standard snapshot, then generate a Subscriber-specific partitioned snapshot.  After generating the snapshots, mark the Subscriber for reinitialization and start the Merge Agent to pull down the schema and data for the filtered subscription.